# In-situ oxygen on Mars - what is MOXIE and SpaceX' ITS relation?

Tags: mars, oxygen, lox

Reading through in-situ methods to manufacture oxygen on Mars, I see the following assets:

- in future, 100x scale of MOXIE would produce up to two kilograms of oxygen per hour
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Oxygen_ISRU_Experiment
  Okay that is, year-demand for one adult will be in place already in 400kg/2=200 hours, or annual production will suffice for a colony of about 40 people. If this oxygen will be just a propellant source before people come, 
  Elon Musk is talking about a propellant plant as well - well those 17 tons of LOX per year are not SO much.
  So how could this LOX factory look like on Mars, and maybe it makes sense after MOXIE succeeds indeed to design something self-replicating?

Comment: 1. at this point, it's too early to tell. 2. it needs to be *reliable* foremost (MOXIE has a very nasty failure mode involving carbon monoxide mixed into the with oxygen; any design easily replicable in-situ will have inferior reliability.)

Answer (score 2):

Considering the challenges of self-replicating it is more likely that more MOXIEs would be shipped in, or a Sabatier reactor if CH4 and LOX is preferred to just LOX and CO.  In parallel for a colony though greenhouses would be started to produce food and oxygen which could supplement the colony and eventually be relied on to add to the breathing supply without importing more hardware for the colony from Earth.